# String between 2 Strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I am currently using the function listed below to find the text between 2 strings, my issue is where nothing is found it just returns an error and I wont to return either a space or Null, can anyone offer any advice on how to alter it please.?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetStringBetween2Strings] 
(
    @String varchar(max), 
    @FirstString varchar(256), 
    @SecondString varchar(256)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(max) 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @FirstPosition int,  @SecondPosition int
    SET @FirstPosition = CHARINDEX(@FirstString,@String) + LEN(@FirstString)
    SET @SecondPosition = CHARINDEX(@SecondString,@String) 
    RETURN (SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @FirstPosition, @SecondPosition - @FirstPosition))

END
```

Comment: What is your input parameters and what is your expected output

Comment: Hi Mansoor, I have re-checked the function and I unfortunately hadn't saved it correctly when I originally created which was causing my original issue.  Though this has fixed the issue that I originally had I thought I would investigate it further.  For example my function call reads like select dbo.udf_GetStringBetween2Strings('<merchant_customer_id> </merchant_customer_id>','<rubbish>','</merchant_customer_id>') as you can see the first thing I am looking for is the string <rubbish> this returns 't_customer_id> where really I would like a sting 'Not Found' as the first string does not exist.

Comment: Did you check my below query.Is it suitable for your expected result..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct way is to check the result of charindex (it returns a 0 when no match is found). e.g.

```
DECLARE @FirstPosition int,  @SecondPosition int
SET @FirstPosition = CHARINDEX(@FirstString,@String) 
if @FirstPosition = 0 return 'Not found'
set @FirstPosition += LEN(@FirstString)
SET @SecondPosition = CHARINDEX(@SecondString,@String, @FirstPosition) 
if @SecondPosition = 0 return 'Not found'   
return SUBSTRING(@String, @FirstPosition, @SecondPosition - @FirstPosition)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this works when one of the parameters is missing but when they are both there its not picking what is between them, it just returns Not Found

Comment: Just tested it and it seems to work, but when pasting an example to and from SO, it didn't. It might be collation or some hidden character. Could you try with a fresh (non pasted) example?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have just tried typing out the whole function from scratch but still getting the same issues I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but did you try typing the sample input? The function itself can be copied pasted, but I got issues after copying pasting the `merchant` example. Retyping that input fixed the issue for me. Also tested with something simple like `select dbo.udf_GetStringBetween2Strings('<a>dfasfas</a>','<a>', '</a>')`, which seems to work after copy/paste as well

Comment: Unfortunately so, I even tried closing and reopening my session of sql server but have the same issue.

Comment: Right I manually type the function and the example in a fresh copy of sql again and it appears to be working now which is so odd as a moment it wasn't, thank you for that it was much appreciated.  Just a thought but if the function finds nothing between the 2 strings that you were looking between is it possible to get it to return Not Found instead of just blank?

Comment: Not sure what happened, probably some character that was a different unicode char under the hood. Anyway hopefully it will keep working now :). About returning 'not found' when empty: you can replace the last if (if secpos=0) with `if @SecondPosition <= @FirstPosition return 'Not found'  ` This will return `Not Found` if the second string is not found, or if its index equals the start position. (if you want to check for whitespaces as well, an extra trimmed variable could be introduced, which value could be checked)

Comment: That works a treat and exactly what I wanted it to do :) I have made your suggestions and it works well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetStringBetween2Strings] 
(
    @String varchar(max), 
    @FirstString varchar(256), 
    @SecondString varchar(256)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(max) 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @FirstSplit VARCHAR(100),@SecondSplit VARCHAR(100),@ReturnStr VARCHAR(100)
    SET @FirstSplit = SUBSTRING(@String,0,CHARINDEX(' ',@String))
    SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX(' ',@String)+1,LEN(@String))
    SET @SecondSplit = @String

    IF @FirstSplit = @FirstString
       SET @ReturnStr =  @FirstSplit
    ELSE IF @SecondSplit = REPLACE(@SecondString,'?','')
      SET @ReturnStr =  @SecondSplit
    ELSE 
      SET @ReturnStr = 'Not Found'    RETURN @ReturnStr END
```

Comment: Hi Mansoor,  Sorry for the delay, I tried your code with my example and the one that I posted here and I get back "</merchant_customer_id??)  I also tired it with this "select dbo.udf_GetStringBetween2Strings('<amount>1</amount>','<amount>','</amount‌​>')" and I get back </amount??>" here I should see 1, I will late cast this to a Decimal value but because of the current result I get an error with converting data type varchar to numeric which is the error I would expect because of the current return result.  Thanks for helping

Comment: I edited my query.Replace ?? field with empty.Now check I got success out put for matched case and "Not found" result for unmatched strings

Comment: Hi Mansoor, I am still getting the same return value as before I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you post your query and passed parameter here

Comment: select dbo.udf_GetStringBetween2Strings('<merchant_customer_id> </merchant_customer_id>','<rubbish>','</merchant_customer_id‌​>') is what I am passing and </merchant_customer_id??> is what is being returned when run

Comment: Check above query I replaced  REPLACE(@SecondString,'?','') instead of @SecondString.Did you change that..?

Comment: I did see your alteration and altered the function accordingly, I have also dropped and recreated it to be on the safe side but still getting the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129027/discussion-between-mansoor-and-pjd).